# Width of the newtons ring

Tags: optics

Why does the width of the newton's rings decreases with order?

I have tried to derive the answer using the formula for diameter of dark and bright rings. but could not come to any conclusion.

so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

For a minimum by reflection $Rm\lambda=r_m^2$ where $r_m$ is the radius of the $m$th dark ring.

Differentiate with respect to the order $m$

$R\lambda=2r_m \dfrac{dr_m}{dm} \Rightarrow \dfrac{dr_m}{dm}=\dfrac{R \lambda}{2 r_m}$

So as $r_m$ increases the rings become closer together.